# I cannot seem to produce the correct output

Tags: c++

So the Mandatory Output is supposed to look like this:

```
Product Name: Orange
Reference Number: 1123452
Price per unit/pound: 0.99
Stock: 34
```

But I have this code that I made that I am having trouble with and I can't figure out what is wrong:

```
    #include <string>
    #include <iostream>

    using namespace std;


    class Product {
    private:
    string prodName;
    double price;
    unsigned refNum, items_remaining;


    public:
        Product (){
            refNum=items_remaining=0; price=0; prodName="";
    }
        Product ( string prod, unsigned ref, double pri, unsigned stk){
            refNum = ref;
            items_remaining = stk;
            prodName = prod;
            price = pri;
        }

        //Add Accessors
        string get_name(string name){
        cin>>name;
        return prodName;
        }
        double get_price (double cost){
        cin>>cost;
        return price;

        }

        unsigned stock (unsigned items){
        cin>>items;
        return items_remaining;
        }
        unsigned sold (unsigned items_remaining, unsigned num_sold){
        items_remaining -= num_sold;
        return items_remaining;
        }

        unsigned addToStock (unsigned items_remaining, unsigned       stock_add){
        stock_add +=items_remaining;
        return items_remaining;

       }
       void info (){
       cout<<"Product Name: "<<prodName<<endl;
       cout<<"Reference Num: "<<refNum<<endl;
       cout<<"Price per unit/pound: "<<price<<endl;
       cout<<"Stock: "<<items_remaining<<endl;


      }




    };
```

The description:

1. The class name should be Product.
2. The class should contain 4 data fields:
   a. Product reference number (unsigned)
   b. Product name (string)
   c. Price per unit/pound (double)
   d. Items/pounds remaining in the store (unsigned)
3. The class should have the following methods:
   a. A constructor that takes all the information as parameters to fill the data fields in the order described above.
   b. An accessor called “get_name” that takes no parameters and returns the name of the product
   c. An accessor called “get_price” that takes no parameters and returns the price of the product
   d. An accessor called “stock” that takes no parameters and returns the number of items/pounds of the current product remaining in the store
   e. A mutator procedure called “sold” that takes in the number of items sold of the current product and updates the value for the number of items remaining in stock
   f. A mutator procedure called “addToStock” that takes in the number of items of the current product that enter into the store and updates the value of items remaining in the store
   g. An accessor called “info” that takes no parameters and displays the information of the product on the screen in the following order, with no spaces between lines. Please DO NOT add any dollar symbols or special character. Just show the names and numbers as
   shown below.

   > ```
   >       Product Name: Orange
   >       Reference Number: 1123456
   >       Price per unit/pound: 0.99
   >       Stock: 34
   > ```

Comment: What is the actual problem?

Comment: You're not manipulating refNum from class Product, which is the value containing the Reference Num, the only line with a value different than the one you're expecting to see.  That means you're passing the value incorrectly to Product.  The mistake isn't therefore in this class.

Comment: you should Post code in simple form refer:- http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask

Answer (score 0):

You need to write a main() function, something like this:

```
int main()
{
    Product a("Orange", 23456, 0.99, 36);
    a.sold(4);
    a.addToStock(2);
    a.info();
}
```

changes you need to do in Product class:

Remove all "cin" from accessors

change

```
unsigned sold(unsigned items_remaining, unsigned num_sold)
```

to

```
unsigned sold( unsigned num_sold)
```

change

```
unsigned addToStock(unsigned items_remaining, unsigned       stock_add)
```

to

```
unsigned addToStock(unsigned       stock_add)
```

change

```
stock_add +=items_remaining;
```

to

```
items_remaining += stock_add;
```

You don't have to pass items_remaining as parameter to methods. The data in the class are directly accessible to the methods of the same class.
Refer: http://www.tutorialspoint.com/cplusplus/cpp_data_encapsulation.htm

Comment: Thank you. I had changed most of the code before reading this but the "Product a" portion is what I was screwing up. I also thank you for pointing out that I had to reorder.

Comment: Also, I can't figure out how to call a class properly inside cpp file.